# Laravel Join with where condition inside not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So my database has two table named **players** and teams, each table has **competitionId** and **teamId** field so my goal is to get all players of a team base on competitionId and teamId of teams table. It only return an empty array.

```
public static function getTeamRoster($competitionId, $teamId) {
        return DB::table('teams as team')
                ->where('team.competitionId', $competitionId)
                ->where('team.teamId', $teamId)
                ->join('players as player', function($join){
                   $join->on('team.competitionId', '=', 'player.competitionId')
                        ->where('player.teamId', 'team.teamId');
                })
                ->get();
    }
```

Comment: because in your code it says `WHERE player.teamID = 'team.teamID' ` I think you want `WHERE player.teamID = 1`. Right?

Comment: In a join just chain `->on()` as opposed to trying to use `->where()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following modified function whether its brings your expected result, if not please be more specific about your requirement,

```
public static function getTeamRoster($competitionId, $teamId) {
    return DB::table('players AS player')
        ->join('teams AS team','player.teamId','=','team.teamId')
        ->where('team.competitionId', $competitionId)
        ->where('team.teamId', $teamId)
        ->get();
}
```